# What is the word for a non-creative task?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> "More Effort" is good for [non-creative] tasks, like building a wall or cleaning your room. But when it comes to creative tasks - like writing a novel or music - it is good to get your mind in a placid state where the work feels effortless.

i.e, it's a task you don't really have to think much about while doing. It's not cognitive, per se.

Comment: *mechanical*, *mundane*, *repetitive*, etc

Comment: How is building a wall not creative??  Certainly the wall is a creation, and more tangible than writing a novel.

Comment: I mean it in a rudimentary sense. 'Designing' is creative; is 'building' not simply following orders?

Comment: Build a wall and let me know.

Comment: @OpenMind You should probably change the title. It seems you want a term for the state of mind and not the task itself.

Comment: "Creative" is an easier word than the mouthful that *right hemisphere of the brain* is. I highly doubt that when I build walls, my left one has more synapses firing. Most blue collar work becomes *menial* after the thousandth time you do it.

Comment: @Mazura 1) Brains don't really work like that. 2) Only menial blue collar work, which I don't think is actually *most* of it at all; with many trades, you're just reaching mastery after a thousand times.

Comment: Unless you intend to give a negative connotation to these non-creative tasks, I'd go with, well, "non-creative"

Comment: @MichaelJ. Just because all the other answers gave negative terms implying mindlessness for this, doesn't mean there aren't non-negative terms for this... [I offered one, "procedural"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/320248/23300), which is widely used especially in medicine for rigid "must be done right each time" tasks.

Comment: It's often possible to get into a zen-like state even when doing rote tasks that can improve your performance.  I doubt the winners of the World Bricklaying Championship go into the say thinking of their work being menial: https://www.google.com/search?q=bricklaying+championship#q=bricklaying+championship&tbm=vid

Answer (score 22):

I would suggest the word "menial". I assume you're trying to draw a contrast between the use of higher and lower function. However, *building a wall* is not as menial as cleaning. Perhaps you should consider changing that piece of your sentence.

**menial** –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/menial)

> noun: used to describe boring or unpleasant work that does not require special skill and usually does not pay much money
>
> adjective: lacking interest or dignity (*a menial task*)

"More Effort" is good for *menial* tasks, but not when it comes to creative tasks.

Comment: Or perhaps your word is not well-suited...

Comment: This is the word I tried to think of, but I kept thinking of *remedial*.

Comment: Why do almost all the answers assume it must be a negative quality? "Menial" wouldn't suit countless non-creative but non-menial skilled, high-focus/high-function tasks where a procedure is followed, from anaesthetising a patient to landing an aeroplane to, well, like in the asker's example, bricklaying (which is a high-skill task).

Comment: @medica When someone asks a question you shouldn't tell them to change it so your answer works better.

Comment: @ringo if that was the consensus opinion the answer would've been down voted more than it has

Comment: I have to agree that this answer is really just wrong.  The OP is about the duality between "creative" and "mechanical" tasks.  By all means, certain "creative" tasks are menial; certain mechanical tasks are menial.  The opposite of menial is something like "managerial".  Again by all means some creative tasks are managerial; some rote tasks are managerial.  This answer, I'm afraid to say, is simply wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 18):

**[Rote](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rote?s=t)**

> 1. routine; a fixed, habitual, or mechanical course of procedure: the rote of daily living.
> 2. proceeding mechanically and repetitiously; being mechanical and repetitious in nature; routine; habitual: rote performance; rote
>      implementation;

Comment: The best answer.

Comment: Actually it's possible "mechanical" is the best answer, but "rote" is equally ideal.

Answer (score 15):

Almost all the existing answers have a negative connotation, and imply the non-creative tasks are unskilled or aren't respect-worthy.

This doesn't suit many highly skilled non-creative tasks, from bricklaying (in the asker's example, [a highly skilled trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bricklayer#Required_training)) to landing a plane or anaesthetising a patient. Here's an answer that works for non-creative tasks of all skill levels.

### Procedural tasks

Example from [Indiana University content](http://www.indiana.edu/~idtheory/methods/m4b.html):

> A procedural task involves performing a procedure, which is a sequence of activities to achieve a goal.

The difference between creative, procedural and declarative aptitudes and knowledge is quite an important one in education research and applied psychology. Here's [an example](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02356776):

[image: I like Bill Butts and I cannot lie]

These are tasks that use "how-to" **[procedural knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_knowledge)**:

> Procedural knowledge, also known as imperative knowledge, is the knowledge exercised in the performance of some task

...which isn't limited to "grunt work", but also includes things like, for example, performing the core procedures involved in a certain type of surgery correctly each time. Much like the asker's example sentence, much education research around learning procedural skills does emphasise the importance of repetition and focussed effort, [for example in  the context of medical training](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15917357):

> Evaluating clinical simulations for learning procedural skills...  (1) Simulations should allow for sustained, deliberate practice within a safe environment, ensuring that recently-acquired skills are consolidated...

Comment: By far the best answer so far. Its only drawback is that _procedural task_ is quite jargony and would likely not be (fully) understood by the average reader of a non-technical text.

Answer (score 6):

A slang term for this is *grunt work*.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/grunt-work

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=grunt+work

Comment: Please paste the definitions into the answer itself, and rely on sources other than urbandictonary.

Comment: "Grunt work" implies unskilled, which is not suggested in the question. Bricklaying in particular is a skilled trade [requiring quite a lot of vocational training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bricklayer#Required_training).

Comment: @user568458, I write software for a living, and a large part of my job is grunt work, even though that's still skilled work. It's just stuff that needs to be done but doesn't take much creativity. "Grunt work" is the term we use among ourselves where I work, in fact. I do agree with you however that building as a whole is not grunt work, and I have much respect for the skill and creativity of builders.

Answer (score 5):

A task that is non-creative, repetitive, and usually boring could be called a ***[chore](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chore)***:

> : a small job that is done regularly
>
> : a dull, unpleasant, or difficult job or experience

[Merriam-Webster]

I feel this word is especially well-suited because it can even be used describe tasks that aren't typically thought of as chores when you want to say a task is boring or tedious.

> *Wall building is such a chore.*

Answer (score 5):

One term that comes to mind is **drudge-work**:

> work that is menial and tedious and therefore distasteful; drudgery.

- http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drudge-work
- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drudge

Answer (score 4):

I think [**mundane**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mundane) or [**unimaginative**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unimaginative) is more appropriate here.

*Menial* always carries a tone of doing something that is less dignified, and I think there is nothing necessarily menial about cleaning your room.

Answer (score 2):

**mechanical**

1
a (1) :  of or relating to machinery or tools    (2) :  produced or operated by a machine or tool   
b :  of or relating to manual operations

2
:  of or relating to artisans or machinists

3
a :  done as if by machine :  seemingly uninfluenced by the mind or emotions :  automatic
b :  of or relating to technicalities or petty matters

4
a :  relating to, governed by, or in accordance with the principles of mechanics 
b :  relating to the quantitative relations of force and matter

5
:  caused by, resulting from, or relating to a process that involves a purely physical as opposed to a chemical or biological change or process 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mechanical

Comment: "mechanical" is the best and clearest answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If the question remains task focused [scut work](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scut+work)  *trivial, unrewarding, tedious, dirty, and disagreeable chores*

If it changes as Phil Sweet suggests perhaps [disengagement](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disengagement) *the act of releasing from an attachment or connection*

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with, [***uncreative***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uncreative%2Cnoncreative&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuncreative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnoncreative%3B%2Cc0)

> *Beauvoir describes woman's situation as contributing to a life of repetitive and uncreative tasks: washing dishes, changing diapers, making food. While these tasks provide the means to an authentic life, they do not constitute creative ends themselves.*
>
> [Ethics and Phenomenology](https://books.google.fr/books?id=YHDym_54lcEC&pg=PA294&dq=%22uncreative+tasks%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4nduIwJjMAhWCcBoKHVQ5AYAQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22uncreative%20tasks%22&f=false)
>
> uncreative
>
> Not having or involving imagination or original ideas:
>   *repetitive and uncreative work*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/definition/anglais/uncreative)

Answer (score 1):

A word which may at least connote what you desire yet whose usage is anything but "everyday, commonplace, or ordinary" would be [quotidian.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quotidian)

Answer (score 1):

Routinary or mechanical

**routinary** 
 *adjective*
Characterized by an adherence to routine; of or relating to routine; mechanical, unvaried; (of a person) that acts according to routine.

**mechanical**
 *adjective*
(Of an action) done without thought or spontaneity; automatic: she stopped the mechanical brushing of her hair

Comment: "mechanical" is the best and clearest answer here.

Answer (score 0):

That would be **in the zone**. It's not necessarily as casual a term as you might suspect.

> informal
>    If you are in the zone, you are ​happy or ​excited because
>   you are doing something very ​skilfully and ​easily.

Cambridge Dictionaries online

**Flow**

> Jeanne Nakamura and Csíkszentmihályi identify the following six
>   factors as encompassing an experience of flow.
>   Intense and focused concentration on the present moment.
>   Merging of action and awareness.
>   A loss of reflective self-consciousness.
>   A sense of personal control or agency over the situation or activity.
>   A distortion of temporal experience, one's subjective experience of time is altered.
>   Experience of the activity as intrinsically rewarding, also referred to as autotelic experience.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)

Comment: If your comment to the OP is accepted the *flow* part of your answer is likely on the money

Answer (score 0):

The word *[servile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/servile)* is used by the Catholic Church to distinguish between intellectual/creative pursuits and manual/non-creative tasks.  I do not know if other churches use similar terminology when describing how to "Honor the Sabbath"

In everyday usage, though, "servile" does seem to carry a negative conmnotation,  but from your example:

> "More Effort" is good for *servile* tasks, like building a wall
>   or cleaning your room

Comment: The linked definitions all strongly imply servitude. Creative work could therefore also be "servile" if it's requested or demanded - in fact, many commercial artists feel more like slaves than artists, even though their work is obviously highly creative.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers come close, but I'd like to suggest

**routine**

Unlike some of the other suggestions, there is no negative connotation of a routine task per se.

Comment: 'Routine' implies regularity, not necessarily a lack of creativity. A creative task could be just as routine as one requiring no creativity, even if the result is different every time.

Comment: @talrnu I think that's a different understanding of "creativity". I'd say that one thing that makes a task creative is that it doesn't follow a set routine, at least not in detail - there are always elements that are invented in the course of the task itself.