# Another word for (sounds like) 'manual' labor/task

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I remember a word that is spelled something like 'meanual' labor or work. It is supposed to mean not manual (physical) but just something which requires a lot of hard work and grinding.

Comment: "grunt work" comes to mind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the word for a non-creative task?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320138/what-is-the-word-for-a-non-creative-task) or http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278922/word-or-phrase-for-tasking-an-expert-with-jobs-that-a-novice-could-do/278940#278940

Comment: "Allergen" - https://youtu.be/Mxek50zVqts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Menial** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/menial)

> *adjective* used to describe boring or unpleasant work that does not require special skill and usually does not pay much money

*"Even the tech optimists admit that many jobs involving menial or repetitive tasks will be automated."*